# Install and print from two identical printers on iMac?

Tags: macos, printing

I have two Dymo label printers. I tried installing the printer using CUPS web admin as well as the Print & Scan under System Preferences. Both printers installed fine. When I print from either the print jobs are sent to only one of the two. The purpose of two printers is to avoid the constant changing of label sizes.

[image]

If it helps: my goal is to have two printers available. One prints large labels. The other prints small labels. When i go to print, I am able to choose which printer to print from.

Comment: Upload a picture of your print settings and print queues. Something is likely wrong in the setup if you can't direct printing to different queues. The app from which you print needs to send jobs to correct queues to get what you desire...

Comment: Thanks bmike. Here are a few screenshots. Are these specific to your request? http://postimg.org/image/zc5fdcvhv/, http://postimg.org/image/hix5umcut/, CUPS: http://postimg.org/image/4cvlu735d/, http://postimg.org/image/80otkz7tj/, http://postimg.org/image/48s532est/

Comment: Perfect, so if you were to rename the printers and queues to say, "Ernie" and "Bert". What happens when you print to Ernie one label?

Comment: I did as you suggested, both are printing to the same label printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dymo label drivers are quite picky and ask that you not connect the devices until the installer asks specifically for the device to be connected. I believe that is to prevent both queues going to the first device in the USB chain, but I don't have two to test with.

I would delete both printer definitions and start with the installer from here:

- https://dymo.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/101/~/dymo-drivers-and-downloads#lw_mac

The read me has the following caution:

> NOTE: Do not connect the USB cable to your computer or USB hub until
>   instructed to do so during the software installation. If you have a
>   label printer already installed, disconnect the USB cable from your
>   computer before running the installer and reconnect the cable when
>   instructed to do so.

So you could try deleting only one queue and then disconnecting the printer that printed from the other queue and try setting up the second printer again.

Comment: Nice one bmike! Thank you for the help. That fixed it. I also realized I put the labels in backwards on one of the printers. Whoops!